# Unable to run wsimport utility in JDK8

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, command-prompt, wsimport

I have JDK8 installed in the directory `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\` and I have my `PATH` Environment Variable set to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\bin`.

Now; in order to use Amazon's Product API I follow their guidelines [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/GSG/GettingSetUp.html) under the Java getting set up section; and I use the following command...

```
wsimport -d ./build -s ./src  -p com.ECS.client.jax http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/AWSECommerceService.wsdl -b jaxws-custom.xml
```

after opening a command prompt in a custom directory I created on my desktop; that custom directory contains the build and src directories as specified in the instructional page provided by Amazon.

Now when I run the command aforementioned; I receive the error...

```
'wsimport' is not recognized as an internal or external command
```

however; if I run `Java -version` within the same command prompt all works well and as expected.

Not sure where to go from here or why it isn't reading through?

Note I already attempted the solutions at [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20920693/wsimport-is-not-recognized-error-in-command-prompt); to no avail.

Comment: Not sure if this is just because of JDK8 but I downgraded to JDK7 and everything works fine.

Comment: You're saying you've installed JRE8. You need a JDK.

Comment: Typo notice the title. Also notice the paths are pointing to JDKs.

Comment: Same thing for me - JDK 7 works fine. The maven build with JDK 8 is failing:
`org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons:jaxws-maven-plugin:2.3:wsimport (wsimport-generate-SampleListener) on project sample-app: Mojo failed - check output`

Answer (score 0):

I found this in the comments section of the following article. I include it here in full because I think it explains why your JDK8/wsimport fails to build and consequently why it works when you switch back to Java7.

http://blog.takipi.com/6-reasons-not-to-switch-to-java-8-just-yet/

Even though the article was written over 3 years ago, I am still having java8/wsimport problems (2017).

> Why not mention some more obvious ones:
>
> 1. The new defaults in Javadoc (called doclint) will break your build. In particular if you are using Maven and some kind of CI (e.g. Hudson,
>      Jenkins) you'll quickly realize that you can't just take your project
>      and build in JDK8. Your build will almost certainly error out because
>      of the new Javadoc. (I have yet to see a project that didn't). The
>      reason is that in Maven a return error code from the javadoc tool will
>      stop the whole release process ... and as I said I have yet to see a
>      project that would not somewhere have a Javadoc doclint noncompliance.
>      Most larger projects (e.g. Netty) seem to solve the problem by simply
>      turning off doclint (which of course wasn't the idea behind doclint)
>      or they stay on JDK7 for a while longer until they iron out all their
>      comments problems.
> 2. Code generation tools in JDK8 (e.g. wsimport) produce code that is not doclint compliant. This is a clear bug and well documented. It
>      means that one part of the JDK8 is not working with another part of
>      the JDK8. Expect to have to circumvent this somehow if you have a web
>      consumer application.